# How to refresh the crystal report?

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports, refresh

Using VB6 AND Crystal Report 9

In my software when i view my report, it is displaying a old data's, if there is any changes in the data's every time i have to refresh my report. How to refresh the report automatically when i run my software.

Code

```
Dim crApp As CRAXDRT.Application
Dim Report As CRAXDRT.Report
Set crApp = New CRAXDRT.Application
Set Report = crApp.OpenReport(App.Path & "\ScheduleReport.rpt")
CRViewer1.ReportSource = Report
CRViewer1.ViewReport
CRViewer1.EnableExportButton = True
CRViewer1.DisplayGroupTree = False
CRViewer1.EnableSearchControl = False
CRViewer1.Zoom (100)
```

I tried CRViewer1.refresh, It showing error

How to refresh the report in my code itself.

Need VB6 code Help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try discarding the saved data before setting the viewers report source

```
Report.DiscardSavedData
CRViewer1.ReportSource = Report
```

Comment: you can also edit the report and un-select the "Save data with report" option under the file menu.

Answer (score 0):

```
'After searching hours...this is the solution for Refresh......
Dim Appl As New CRAXDRT.Application
Dim rpt As New CRAXDRT.Report

Private Sub CRV1_RefreshButtonClicked(UseDefault As Boolean)
    CRV1.Refresh
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Activate()
    CRV1_RefreshButtonClicked True   'This EVENT IS IMPORTANT FOR REFRESH
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
    ReportPath = App.Path & "\YourReportFile.rpt"
    Set Appl = New CRAXDRT.Application
    Set rpt = Appl.OpenReport(ReportPath)
    If rpt.HasSavedData Then rpt.DiscardSavedData
    rpt.VerifyOnEveryPrint = True
    CRV1.ReportSource = rpt
    CRV1.Refresh
    CRV1.ViewReport
End Sub
```